# Microphone closing on Nest Hub - other devices work

Tags: actions-on-google, actions-builder

We use the Conversational Actions SDK and our action (an interactive audio book) works in the Actions console and on the iPhone Google Assistant app without any problem.
However, on Nest Hub devices its behavior is completely different: it takes very long before it starts playing the SSML audio and after nearly every answer the microphone is closed, so that you have to say "OK, Google" again. That really kills the flow of the game. As everything works fine in the console we have a very hard time debugging this issue.

That is an example for a response that we send to the webhook request:

```
{
    "user": {
        "params": {
            "id": "google-d1d76b00-e220-11ea-bf59-123456789"
        }
    },
    "scene": {
        "next": {
            "name": "GameFlow"
        },
        "slots": {
            "GameFlowResponse": {
                "mode": "REQUIRED",
                "status": "SLOT_UNSPECIFIED"
            }
        }
    },
    "prompt": {
        "firstSimple": {
            "text": "Some text to be displayed",
            "speech": "<speak><audio src=\"https://some.audio.url\">Some text</audio><break time=\"500ms\"/><audio src=\"https://another.audio.url\">some text</audio></speak>"
        }
    }
}
```

Did maybe anyone experience something similar to that? As I said, I am running out of knowledge how to debug this.

Comment: So this isn't happening when you run it in the Simulator on Smart Display mode? Do you see similar issues if you remove the "speech" prompt (leaving just the "text" prompt) or if you omit the audio URLs? Do you see any lag in querying for the audio URLs? Does this happen even if you don't transition to another scene?

Comment: So this isn't happening when you run it in the Simulator on Smart Display mode?
Yes (it is not happening in the simulator).

Do you see similar issues if you remove the "speech" prompt (leaving just the "text" prompt)
Yes, still the same.

... or if you omit the audio URLs?
Yes, still the same. If I don't use audio it still takes "ages".

Do you see any lag in querying for the audio URLs?
No - loaded from CDN.

Does this happen even if you don't transition to another scene?
Yes.

Comment: Also the display of the text is "broken": https://www.dropbox.com/s/ysr9wuqxk1zlant/cobra.png?dl=0

Comment: Are you using the Interactive Canvas anywhere in your Action?

Comment: No, nothing. We started just with the basics and want to build up from there. Basically every response looks like the example.